# Use name as subdomain in url

Tags: kentico

I am using kentico 9 solution where i have one url like below:

```
localhost/Home.aspx
```

Now i have to add one name like subdomain.Below is the example:

```
localhost/vikash/Home.aspx
```

If I try to use this URL it is redirecting me to error page. But here I want it to accept any name here.

Or in settings> Url&Seo >DefaultUrlPathPrefix: in this section if i add any name it is working fine. can we make this field configurable, That can accept any string value there.

Can i have any idea regarding this?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Hi Koby, Thanks for your quick reply. I am getting 404 not found.

Comment: Can you send a snapshot of yout project directory ?

Comment: project directory means the solution structure?

Comment: Yes - the solution tree / structure

Comment: You have to configure routing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: in the same folder your Home.aspx file is found - open a new folder call it vikash, and place Home.aspx in it.

Comment: Hi Stavm, This name "vikash" i given as example there can be any name.

Comment: @Vikash, then call the folder in whatever name you want

Comment: @Stavm, This is kentico 9 solution so there is no physical folder used in solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wildcard URLs.

https://docs.kentico.com/k9/configuring-kentico/configuring-page-urls/wildcard-urls

You could perform URL redirects to the target site on the Home page depending on the wildcard parameter in the URL.

Another option would be to set URL aliases on the target page according to the URL path you may need.

If you use a subdomain like "vikash.localhost/home.aspx" you could use site domain aliases.
But this will not work for URL paths.

Comment: currently i have to use string as subdomain like mydomain/anysubdomainname/Home.aspx and it should work for accessing any page like if again i have to visit any other page that subdomainname should not be erase from url for the new access path. Can we set our settings settings> Url&Seo >DefaultUrlPathPrefix based on subdomain? If we are able to then it will work every where. Or in this case wildcard url will work?

Comment: If you would use a "real" subdomain, you could set the default URL path for each subdomain in the site settings (domain aliases). But this is only working for subdomains. In your case, you use always the same domain (localhost).

So if you have to keep the path variant (same domain, different pathes to Home), I think the easiest way would be to create a page node for each name variant (here vikash), and set up the page tree below these nodes redundantly.

I think it would be the easiest way to use subdomains in your case.

Comment: I know this solution but i am looking for some different solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I've worked in solutions like this before they had the sub directories setup as an application below the main site in IIS.

So in IIS you need to right click the main site, click Add Application, add the name of the application (which will be your sub directory name) and point it to the location on the hard drive where Kentico resides.

Answer (score 0):

I write one custom httpmodule and put my logic over there and it is working fine.Thanks for all your support.